# Implementation of Long Atomic Int

Tags: c++, multithreading, counter, atomic

I would like to use an atomic counter (multi-thread computation) that counts to typically 2^40, so I cannot use a 32 bit int atomic counter directly. I do not have c++11 yet (I will migrate to it but not yet as this has a cost for me) and I have to compile on 32bit and 64bit platforms.
I use QT currently, so I can use QAtomicInt.

Here is what I'm thinking of:

```
(initialization...)
QAtomicInt counterLo = 0;
QAtomicInt counterHi = 0;


void increment()
{
    int before = counterLo.fetchAndAddOrdered(1);
    if(before==INT_MAX)
    {
        counterHi.fetchAndAddOrdered(1); //Increment high word
        counterLo.fetchAndAddOrdered(INT_MAX);    //Increments low word to -1
        counterLo.fetchAndAddOrdered(1);   //Increments low word to 0
    }         
}

uint64_t value()
{
    //Wait until the low word is non-negative
    int lo = counterLow;
    while(lo<0)
        lo = counterLow;

    return (uint64_t)counterHi * ((uint64_t)INT_MAX+1) + (uint64_t)lo;
}
```

Is this correct? I already tried to make the counter with a mutex, but I'm loosing around 10% performance. This is called about 1 million times a second, shared between 8 threads (sample counter for Monte-Carlo simulation)

Thanks!

Comment: A sequence of two separate atomic operations is really not the same as one single atomic operation... :-(  But even the whole `if` construct is massively non-atomic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not overall atomic, see the following example:

- `hi=0,lo=INT_MAX`
- T1 calls `value()`, gets `lo=INT_MAX`, is interrupted
- T2 calls `increment()` increments hi to 1
- T1 resumes and reads `counterHi`, gets 1, returns a value of 2^32 + INT_MAX

This is likely not what you want. Can't you just split your sample space and let each thread calculate n/8 items without contending for a lock?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is not atomic. Sequence of atomic operations can be interrupted. I recommend to use protection (Mutex or critical section).